# Htaccess Rewrite Rule with regex

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the below rule avaialbe in my htaccess to forward parmanantly to new location with some exception like 'cosa', 'index.php'.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cosa
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/cosa/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I want to add another exception `([a-z0-9A-Z]){1,12}` if the url has any number or digit of maximum 12 charcter it has to go to index.php page.

If I entered:

`mydomain/somethinh1` -> `mydomain/index.php`

`mydomain/12ngohere` -> `mydomain/index.php`

Comment: @HeroFTime, this is same as i wrote, but its not working. Please tell me how to use this...

Comment: Careful: that regex here in the comments does not exactly match what you ask for. I understand it such that you want to match only those patterns that hold a number at one position which may consist of 1 to 12 digits.

Comment: @arkascha Leading slash for `REQUEST_URI` is needed

Comment: @arkascha This is true when you are into `RewriteRule` but not for `REQUEST_URI` since it always contains path with leading slash `/something/other/thing/etc`

Comment: @JustinIurman you are absolutely right, sorry for the confusion! I removed that confusing intial comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a separate rule in addition to the above:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z_]*([0-9]{1,12})[a-zA-Z_]*$ index.php
```

So taking all together:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z_]*[0-9]{1,12}[a-zA-Z_]*$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cosa$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/cosa/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Another note: I also added two `$` to those RewriteCond lines to prevent exceptions for requests to stuff like (for example) `/cosanostra` and `/index.phpideas.pdf`...

Comment: thank you, but the rule is not working. I'll modify about the slash. could you please correct it

Comment: "is not working" does not help here. What happens? And what should I modify? Why and towards what?

Comment: I think I might be wrong in explaination. What I need is if someone type domain/somthing it should add to exception. The rule should not apply to it. Like you see on !^cosa$. I want to read this in index.php page.

Comment: I re-added those leading `/` in the RewriteCond lines because they _are_ indeed required as @JustinIurman correctly pointed out above.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the logic in your last comment. Could you please reword it? From your question I understand that you want to redirect requests to such a url with "a number in it" to the index.php page. That is what the code above does. But now this is _not_ what you want? Just adding another "exception" (RewriteCond) would _not_ rewrite such requests to the index page.

Comment: My concern is i want to read the link in my index.php file and than I will redirect using php. like domain/job than I will redirect it from php domain.com?looking=job. Just I want from you, if someone enter domain.com/somthing it should not diverted to http://www.mydomain.com/cosa/$1 [R=301,L] which is doing now. Conclusion is domain.com/somthing should be add to rule exception. Or you can make it domain.com/somthing turns to domain.com/index.php/somthing

Comment: Sorry, that is not what you ask in the question. And I don't see the connection here from an exception about .../something to those urls with numbers in them. I suggest you first get really clear what you want and _then_ ask in a precise manner. You will never be able to redirect on php level when you don't initially rewrite the requests to the index.php page at all. Instead you will either get a 404 error or some arbitrary object.

Comment: just I want domain.com/something goes to domain.com/index.php/something thats it..

Comment: Sorry, that again is something totally different. Also you don't answer to questions. You won't get a useful answer like this. Sorry, you have to understand that it does not help to ask something a bit, by indicating somewhere what you might want. Either you are precise or there is no way to give you help.

Comment: i gave u the answer, but but your code `RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z_]*[0-9]{1,12}[a-zA-Z_]*$ index.php [L]` is taking me to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/cosa/$1 [R=301,L]` which I dnot want

Comment: First what answer? Where _is_ the conenction between `/something` and those "urls with numbers in them" you originally started with? Second a RewriteRule does _never_ "take you to" another rule, what are you talking about? And third that redirection to index.php stops after matching because of the `[L]` flag, no further rewriting is done, index.php is executed, if it does not exist an error is raised.

Comment: Ok, that happens. As suggested before: try to get clear to yourself what you are _really_ looking for. Then you are welcome to ask here and you will find many experienced people willing to help. Have a great day!